# Windows Storage Server 2003 R2 RDP Disconnection

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, rdp

I am unable to remote desktop to our Windows Storage Server 2003 R2 machine.

There are a few people about with [similar](http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/cant-rdp-server-2003-server-w-endpoint-protection-manager-11xx-installed) [issues](http://www.mombu.com/microsoft/microsoft/t-remote-desktop-problems-wss-2003-r2-2944875.html) but no answers around. Symantec End Point is installed but no network protection.

Using rdesktop in Linux I receive:

```
ERROR: send: Connection reset by peer
NOT IMPLEMENTED: PDU 12
ERROR: Connection closed
```

Where the "PDU XX" number changes on each connection.

In windows using the latest mstsc I receive:

```
The connection was lost due to a network error. Try connecting again. 
If the problem persists, contact your network Administrator.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried turning Symantec completely off temporarily?

Comment: unfortunately not something I can try at the moment but will asap

Comment: Are there any errors in the Application or System Event Logs?

Answer (score 1):

Drivers. Check for the latest drivers, DISABLE TCP OFFLOADING / CHIMNEY. Some drivers around are crappy like hell.

Comment: I've thought along similar lines for another issue, I'll try this here, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First try remoting in with a windows machine using the latest RDP client (found in windows update or available [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925876)).  If that doesn't work I'd remove symantec endpoint protection (on a side note I'm suprised endpoint protection actually installed at all on storage server as storage server is missing alot of core windows functionality but it's good to note that it apparently can be installed)

Comment: sorry; should have been clearer. MSTSC == RDP client, and unfortunately the comments regarding me been unable to stop endpoint at this point are still true.

Answer (score 0):

is port 3389 open?  If you have nmap open you can scan the machine, but if not you can run `telnet machinename 3389` from within cmd.exe.  If it's not open, it'll say "Could not open connection to machinename on port 3389: Connection Failed", but if successful it'll give you a blank window.

Comment: Port 3389 is open, it allows me to connect to RDP, just not see anything.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like your server ports are being closed by something. Check all your security settings.